# enter a blank line to stop asking input but i have to enter twice

Tags: java, oop

I have to write a java program that asks users to enter data values, until they enter a blank line. But I have a problem that I have to `enter` twice to stop asking input and i only can solve this problem when adding a `System.out.prinln()` line. How can i fix it, pleas help me.

This is my code:

```
System.out.println("Enter components: ");
    Set<String> comps = new Set<>();
    while (true) {
        String comp = scan.nextLine();
        if (comp.equals("")) {
            break;
        } else {
            comps.insert(comp);
            scan.nextLine();     // also if i remove this line, the input only asked twice
            System.out.println();     // can solve the prob when add this
        }
    }
```

When i run my program, it will asks for the input like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihjUX.png)

Comment: I don't understand why you have the second `scan.nextLine();` in your loop.

Comment: because if i delete it, the program just asks for input twice, and then the loop will break.

Answer (score 0):

You only need one `Scanner` `nextLine` call.

```
System.out.println("Enter components: ");
Set<String> comps = new Set<>();
while (true) {
    String comp = scan.nextLine();
    if (comp.equals("")) {
        break;
    } else {
        comps.insert(comp);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you need to feed only one empty line and the loop will break.

```
String comp = scan.nextLine();

while (!comp.equals("")) {
    comps.add(comp);
    comp = scan.nextLine();
}
```

Comment: if i do this, the program just asks for input twice and then the loop will break.